# Draggable panel onclick z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of panels with jquery ui draggable option, but when i click in one of the panels it's moves below the others panels. I want to do that when i click the clicked panel got a z-index higher than everybody else, so by this way it's shows over the others panels.

JSFiddle:

HTML structure of the panel:

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div id="14" class="panel panel-off2">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">

      <div class="ptitle">Task 14</div>
    <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="14"></span>
<div class="miniswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="14">
    <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
</div> 
  </div> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

HTML structure of the row of panels.

```
  <div id="tasksList" class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="1" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 1</div>

          <div class="optiongroup">  <span  data-toggle="modal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="1"></span>


    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="12">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="uri" value="uri">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test/task1</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="2" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 2</div>
           <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="2"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="12">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test/task2</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="3" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 3</div>
        <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="3"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="3">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="4" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 4</div>
         <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="4"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="4">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="5" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 5</div>
         <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="5"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="5">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="6" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 6</div>
        <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="6"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="6">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="7" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 7</div>
         <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="7"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="7">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="8" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 8</div>
         <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="8"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="8">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="9" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 9</div>
        <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="9"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="9">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="10" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 10</div>
         <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="10"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="10">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="11" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 11</div>
         <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="11"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="11">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="12" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

           <div class="ptitle">Task 12</div>
     <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="12"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="12">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="13" class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

           <div class="ptitle">Task 13</div>
         <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="13"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="13" checked>
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="14" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 14</div>
        <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="14"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="14">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div id="15" class="panel panel-off2">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">

          <div class="ptitle">Task 15</div>
         <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="15"></span>
    <div class="miniswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-id="15">
        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
    </div> 
      </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Z-index by default of the panels:

```
 .ui-draggable { z-index: 10;}
```

Onclick event (i put z-index 100 but it's apply to all the panels, not only the clicked):

```
$( ".panel" ).click(function () {
  $(.ui-draggable').css( "z-index", "100 !important;" );
  });
```

Panel is draggable and resizable by this:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".panel" ).draggable();
    $( ".panel" ).resizable();
  });
```

Comment: the problem is that after you try to move all of the divs, with your logic, all of them will be at the same z-index... you should find the one with higher z-index and increase by one for the clicked div. or try to set the z-index of all divs to 0 and set to 100 the one of the clicked div. sorry, my english is not the best

Comment: verify my updated answer. its working

Answer (score 0):

You can target the clicked element by using $(this).

```
$( ".panel" ).click(function () {
    $(this, '.ui-draggable').css( "z-index", "100;" );
});
```

Also, !important will not work, so remove this. If you really want to apply it, you should do it why style():

```
jQuery.style(name, value, priority);
```

Comment: I don't want to apply the z-index 100 to the class ".panel", i want to apply it to the class "ui-draggable".

Comment: Please see my updated answer. This will add the z-index to the .ui-draggable inside the .panel you click.

Comment: ( It doesn't worked (the panel that I clicked doesn't bring up) $( ".panel" ).click(function () {
    $(this, '.ui-draggable').css( "z-index", "100;" );
  });

Comment: Try this: `$( ".panel" ).click(function () { $(this).closest('.ui-draggable').css( "z-index", "100" ); });`

Answer (score 0):

you should use this

```
$(this).css('z-index', '100 !important;');
```

instead of

```
$('.ui-draggable').css( "z-index", "100 !important;" );
```

but before this you should do

```
$('.ui-draggable').css( "z-index", "0" );
```

to bring back all the divs

$(this) will ensure that you are working only with the clicked div.

**EDIT:**
I found the problem. You should use the 'dragstart' event to change the z-index of the divs. to drag an element you are not clicking, your are dragging, thats why the click event is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.square').draggable();
    $('.square').on('dragstart', function(event, ui) {
        var maxZIndex = 0;
        $('.square').each(function() {
            if(this.style.zIndex > maxZIndex)
                maxZIndex = this.style.zIndex;
        });
        $(this).css('z-index', maxZIndex + 1);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2DH4f/1/

**EDIT 2**
Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2DH4f/3/

Comment: (This doesn't worked...) $( ".panel" ).click(function () {
  $(this).css('z-index', '100 !important;');
  $('.ui-draggable').css( "z-index", "0" );
  });

Comment: @Pedro invert the lines... you should put back all the divs before bring front the one you clicked. like this:  $( ".panel" ).click(function () {  $('.ui-draggable').css( "z-index", "0" ); $(this).css('z-index', '100 !important;'); });

Comment: $( ".panel" ).click(function () { $('.ui-draggable').css( "z-index", "0" ); $(this).css('z-index', '100 !important;'); }); It doesn't worked (the panel that I clicked doesn't bring up)

Comment: excuse me i don't understand, the code is in the $( ".panel" ).click(function () { i think, right?

Comment: check the EDIT... we should use 'dragstart'